# OpenLayers - Vector clipping a layer using multiple features

Tags: openlayers, clip

I have a project where I need to clip away the full OSM map except inside a few features. In order to do so I have found an example on the OpenLayers website: [example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/layer-clipping-vector.html).

I have implemented this example into my own codebase and found that it works fine when trying to clip a single feature out of the the background map. But when you try to clip multiple features, then the full map will be left blank and nothing is being clipped out.

In the code below I first filter all the towns using their code. If the code is included in a list of codes, then it is pushed into the array of features. These features are then added to the vectorsource `vectorSource.addFeatures(this.townFeatures);`.

Then I follow the example and clip my OSM layer using the vectorsource. I also want to mention that the OSM layer is part of LayerGroup and positioned as the first element of this group:

```
      vectorSource.on('addfeature', () => {
        this.map.getLayers().getArray()[0].setExtent(vectorSource.getExtent());
      });

      this.map
        .getLayers()
        .getArray()[0]
        .on('postrender', (e) => {
          var vectorContext = getVectorContext(e);
          e.context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in';
          vectorSource.forEachFeature((feature) => {
            console.log(feature);
            vectorContext.drawFeature(feature, style);
          });
          e.context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
        });
```

Bellow you can see the full code I use in order to load in the layer and clip the OSM layer.

```
   addTownshipLayer() {
      let vectorSource = new VectorSource({
        format: new GeoJSON(),
        minScale: 15000000,
        loader: (extent) => {
          let url =
            'http://localhost:8081/geoserver/township/wfs?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=1.1.0&typename= township:Refship&srsname=EPSG:3857&outputFormat=application/json&count=1000&bbox=' +
            extent.join(',') +
            ',EPSG:3857';
          let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.open('GET', url);
          let onError = () => {
            vectorSource.removeLoadedExtent(extent);
          };
          xhr.onerror = onError;
          xhr.onload = () => {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
              this.removeFeature('townShipLayer');
              let features = vectorSource
                .getFormat()
                .readFeatures(xhr.responseText);
              this.townFeatures = [];
              features.forEach((feature) => {
                if (this.towncodes.includes(feature.getProperties().code)) {
                  feature.setId(feature.get('OIDN'));
                  feature.setStyle(townStyle);
                  this.townFeatures.push(feature);
                }
                vectorSource.addFeatures(this.townFeatures);
              });
            } else {
              onError();
            }
          };
          xhr.send();
        },
        strategy: bboxStrategy,
      });

      var style = new Style({
        fill: new Fill({
          color: 'black',
        }),
      });

      vectorSource.on('addfeature', () => {
        this.map.getLayers().getArray()[0].setExtent(vectorSource.getExtent());
      });

      this.map
        .getLayers()
        .getArray()[0]
        .on('postrender', (e) => {
          var vectorContext = getVectorContext(e);
          e.context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in';
          vectorSource.forEachFeature((feature) => {
            console.log(feature);
            vectorContext.drawFeature(feature, style);
          });
          e.context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
        });

      let vector = new Vector({
        source: vectorSource,
      });
      vector.set('name', 'townShipLayer');
      this.map.addLayer(vector);
      this.mapLoaded = true;
    }
```

Comment: The example code would clip where all the features overlapped.  To clip where any of the features have coverage you would need to create a single MultiPolygon geometry and clip with that, for example https://codesandbox.io/s/layer-clipping-vector-forked-jez2g

Comment: @Mike Thank you very much. This fixed my problem!